# error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am attempting to create a simple base class and another class that inherits from it. I am getting the following error.

`guard_room.h:17:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token`

I have looked at other posts and it seems like I have a circular dependency somewhere but I have done everything I have read to resolve it. Here are my classes

**Base class room.h:**

```
#ifndef _room
#define _room

template <typename U, typename T>
class room
{
    public:

        //default constructor
        room();

        //overloaded constructor
        room(U, T);


        //getters/setters
        void set_treasure(T);
        void set_name(U);
        T get_treasure() const;
        U get_name() const;

    private:

        U name;

        //room monster
        //monster room_monster

        T treasure;

};

#include "room.tem"

#endif
```

**Inherited class guard_room.h:**

```
#ifndef _guard_room
#define _guard_room

template <typename U, typename T> class room;

template <typename U, typename T>
class guard_room : public room
{
    public:

        //default constructor
        guard_room();

        //overloaded constructor
        guard_room(U, T, T) : room(U, T);

        //battle function?
        void battle();

    private:
        T dummy;

};

#include "guard_room.tem"
#endif
```

I am also thoroughly confused in where I need to put the includes for the base room class in my inherited class. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your derived class needs to be able to see the entire definition of your base class - you'll need to include the header at the top of the derived class' file.  (a base class *extends* a derived class, so the base class is very much a part of the derived class)

Also, *room* is a template and not a class - you can only inherit from a concrete class, so you need to specify the template parameters.  i.e.

```
#include "room.h"

template <typename U, typename T>
class guard_room : public room<U, T>
```

Lastly - do your `.tem` files also contain header guards?   (If not, you'll need those in there too to avoid other compiler errors)

---

Also, be aware that an initialiser list is part of a constructor's definition, so the following is invalid

```
    guard_room(U, T, T) : room(U, T);
```

If your constructor definition is elsewhere, then all you want here is

```
    guard_room(U, T, T);
```

otherwise, it might just be enough to write

```
    guard_room(U u, T t1, T t2) : room(u, t1) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The particular syntax of inheritance with templates is something I have not dealt with before.

Comment: I've edited the post - credit to other answers in the thread (Justin and Ben) for pointing out the error in the initialisation list.

Answer (score 2):

You are supplying half the implementation of the constructor here

```
//overloaded constructor
guard_room(U, T, T) : room(U, T);
```

*If* you want the implementation to be inline, you have to add the constructor body as well.

```
//overloaded constructor
guard_room(U, T, T) : room<U, T>()
{ }
```

---

When the implementation of the constructor is also included in the `.tem` file at the end of the header (as indicated in the comments), the real solution is to just remove the reference to the base class from the constructor declaration and leave that to the separate definition.

```
//overloaded constructor
guard_room(U, T, T);
```

Comment: Ah I see what your saying but in my `guard_room.tem` I have the following constructor `template <typename U, typename T>
guard_room<U, T>::guard_room( U new_name, T amount, T new_dum) : room (new_name, amount)
{
    this->dummy = new_dum;

}    `

Comment: Ok, then you should remove the `: room(U, T)` from the header. Either way will work.

Comment: Justin's now-deleted answer made an important point: the *ctor-initializer-list* needs actual parameters, not types.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Yes, I just noticed that. This isn't working wery well anyway, as the real implementation is also included later.

Comment: +1 for pointing out my mistake with the constructor. Thanks for your help.