# Non-template Inheritance from a template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, g++

OS: Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon
g++: 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)

I am getting the following errors from inheriting a template class from a non-template class in g++:

```
In file included from common/bChain.h:13:0,
                 from common/bProtein.h:12,
                 from common/bProtein.cpp:12:
common/bPeptide.h:27:31: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
common/bPeptide.h:27:31: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
common/bPeptide.h:27:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

Several similar questions have been asked here:

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265861/error-expected-class-name-before-token-with-templates (template inheriting from template)
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548742/c-inheritance-and-templates-not-compiling (uninitialized members in base class)
```

but each of them answers a different problem. [This post](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/732233-expected-template-name-before-token-template-class-inheritance-virtual-method) suggests the following should work with VisualStudio I think is an error with g++. This post comes the closest, but doesn't quite address the issue.

I have three classes, `VertexSet`, `Peptide`, and `Chain`. `VertexSet` is a template class, `Peptide` is a non-template class that inherits from `VertexSet`, and `Chain` inherits from Peptide:

`VertexSet.h`:

```
#ifndef B_VERTEXSET_H
#define B_VERTEXSET_H

//////////////// STL
#include <vector>

//////////////// project
#include <Vertex.h>
#include <Spatial.h>
#include <Pool.h> // for pool resources

namespace griddock { template <typename T> class VertexSet; };

/** @brief \c VertexSet \c
 *  @author     Stephen J. Bush
 *  @copyright  Creative Commons Attribution Non-Commercial License V2.0
 *  @copyright  Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike License V3.0
 *  @par
 */
template <typename T>
class griddock::VertexSet
   :  virtual public Spatial
{
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //       Tor
protected:
   VertexSet();
   VertexSet(const VertexSet &rhs);
public:
   ~VertexSet();

   /* ... more functions here ...*/
};

#define GVXS   griddock::VertexSet<T>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///@name          Tor
///@{
template <typename T>
GVXS::VertexSet()
   :  vertex_(),
      min_(),
      max_()
{
}

template <typename T>
GVXS::VertexSet(const VertexSet &rhs)
   :  vertex_(rhs.vertex_),
      min_(),
      max_()
{
}


template <typename T>
GVXS::~VertexSet()
{
   clear();
}

///@}
//                .
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#undef GVXS

#endif
```

`Peptide.h`

```
#ifndef B_PEPTIDE_H
#define B_PEPTIDE_H

//////////////// STL
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//////////////// project
#include <Pool.h>
#include <Residue.h>
#include <Spatial.h>
#include <Vertex.h>
#include <VertexSet.h>
#include <File.h>
#include <IPeptide.h>

namespace griddock { class Peptide; };


/** @brief \c Peptide \c implements a data structure to store protein residues
 *  @author     Stephen J. Bush
 *  @copyright  Creative Commons Attribution Non-Commercial License V2.0
 *  @copyright  Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike License V3.0
 *  @par
 */
class griddock::Peptide
   :  virtual public VertexSet<Residue>,
      virtual public IPeptide
{
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //       Tor
public:
   Peptide();
   Peptide(const Peptide &peptide);
   ~Peptide();

   /* ...other functions here...*/

};

#endif
```

`Peptide.cpp`

```
//////////////// header
#include <Peptide.h>

//////////////// STL
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//////////////// project
#include <Residue.h>
#include <File.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace griddock;

#define GPEP   Peptide

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///@name          Tor
///@{
GPEP::Peptide()
   :  VertexSet<Residue>()
{
}

GPEP::Peptide(const Peptide &peptide)
   :  VertexSet<Residue>(),
      vertex_(peptide.vertex_),
      chainid_(peptide.chainid_)
{
}


GPEP::~Peptide()
{
   clear();
}

///@}
//                .
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Turns out all I needed was to make sure that `Chain` explicitly called the `Peptide` constructor: `Chain() : Peptide() {}`

Comment: Tried it. Have to wait 8 hours before posting my own answer =/. It's kind of funny how StackOverflow is my [teddy bear](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/debugging.html)

Comment: You should learn about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): Short, Self-Contained, Compilable Examples (or not compilable in your case). Often time by reduced the issue to its barest requirements the solution will pop up by itself... that and the question would be more interesting; as it is you provided a wall of text (so long!) and yet failed to provide `bChain.h` which is mentioned in the diagnostic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was to make sure that `Chain` explicitly called the `Peptide` constructor: `Chain() : Peptide() {}`